# is there a beautiful way to module a number or cycle(4) in a each?

Tags: ruby

```
> a = %w[foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5 foo6]
 => ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4", "foo5", "foo6"] 


> a.each_with_index {|b,i| puts "b #{i}"; puts "== mod4 "  if i%4==0}
b 0
== mod4 
b 1
b 2
b 3
b 4
== mod4 
b 5
```

I have an `array a` . I  want to iterate every element and puts something every 4 element.
However, 
`if i%4 == 0` is too ugly . Is there a beautiful to achieve this ?

Comment: why do you think it's ugly? just do the right indentation and split that huge string into two smallers and it would be ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is quite unusual. What about boundary conditions?

Maybe you can use `each_slice` successfully?

```
a.each_slice(4) do |group|
  group.each{|i| p i}
  puts "== mod4"
end

# Prints:
"foo1"
"foo2"
"foo3"
"foo4"
== mod4
"foo5"
"foo6"
== mod4
```

Comment: I think this is more rubist way? Isn't it ? :D  Thanks.